# Fix regular expression

Tags: python, regex

I am writing one regular expression but there seems some issue. Here are the strings

```
Mariahilfer Str 45/II 22-24
Mariahilfer Str 45/Top 46 - Raimundhof
Mariahilfer Str 77 Generali-Center OG Top 224
Mariahilfer Str 45/Top 49/Raimundhof
Kohlmarkt 7
Kohlmarkt 8-10
Kohlmarkt 16/1/25a
```

Following is the my Regular expression

```
(.*)\s\d{1,}
```

I need the following output

```
Mariahilfer Str
Mariahilfer Str
Mariahilfer Str
Mariahilfer Str
Kohlmarkt
Kohlmarkt
Kohlmarkt
```

Comment: How is your code not working? How are you using the regular expression in python code?

Comment: Your pattern was fine except that you were using a greedy match. Change to lazy matching -> `.*?`

Comment: Using my regular expression it gives me output as following Mariahilfer Str 45/II
Mariahilfer Str 45/Top
Mariahilfer Str 77 Generali-Center OG Top
Mariahilfer Str 45/Top
Kohlmarkt
Kohlmarkt
Kohlmarkt

Comment: I am checking in regex buddy for now. Later on i need to use in python using re.findall(regex,string)

Comment: Your expected output doesn't contain any numerals, which is what `\d` matches.

Answer (score 3):

Match everything up to a digit; perhaps with a look-ahead for the space:

```
\D+(?=\s)
```

Your expression was using a *greedy* match, allowing for extra digits to be captured; the expression would match on the *last* space and digit combination in your input. You could fix your pattern by using `.*?`; e.g. a non-greedy match.

Demo:

```
>>> import re
>>> sample = '''\
... Mariahilfer Str 45/II 22-24
... Mariahilfer Str 45/Top 46 - Raimundhof
... Mariahilfer Str 77 Generali-Center OG Top 224
... Mariahilfer Str 45/Top 49/Raimundhof
... Kohlmarkt 7
... Kohlmarkt 8-10
... Kohlmarkt 16/1/25a
... '''.splitlines()
>>> pattern = re.compile(r'\D+(?=\s)')
>>> for line in sample:
...     print repr(pattern.search(line).group())
... 
'Mariahilfer Str'
'Mariahilfer Str'
'Mariahilfer Str'
'Mariahilfer Str'
'Kohlmarkt'
'Kohlmarkt'
'Kohlmarkt'
```

Comment: @hjpotter92: indeed, better still

Comment: Yea all you need `\D+` without a `global` flag (assuming that the lines are being read one at a time).

Comment: the last space will be included to the result. it's also not clear why the original regex didn't work.

Comment: OP was using a greedy quantifier so it matches past what OP wanted